# Node.js does not find a file

Tags: node.js

For some reason my `module.exports` is not exporting the database module as expected. I am fairly new to node, so have no idea what is the issue.

The file `database.js`

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize('', '', '', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8006',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
        freezeTableName: true,
    },
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
    },
    operatorsAliases: false,
})

let models = [
    import('./db/orders.js'),
]

models.forEach(model => {
    const seqModel = model(sequelize, Sequelize)
    db[seqModel.name] = seqModel
})

Object.keys(db).forEach(key => {
    if ('associate' in db[key]) {
        db[key].associate(db)
    }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

export default db
```

The import in `app.js`

```
import db from './database';
```

The error `Cannot find module '/var/www/html/orders-service/database' imported from /var/www/html/orders-service/app.js Did you mean to import ../database.js?`

Both `app.js` and `database.js` are in the same folder.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Have you tried it? You problem has nothing todo with "my module.exports is not exporting the database module"

Comment: then what does it have to do with? do you have a solution?

Comment: Use the `require` keyword instead of `import`. `const db = require('./database.js')`

Comment: I can't because I have `type`: `module`

Comment: @Denis `Cannot find module '/var/www/html/orders-service/database'` Your path to the module is wrong. If it has something to do with "module.exports" you would get a type error or similar, and not "module/file not found".... Read the error message, and understand what it means! Whats your cwd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the .js file extension to the file path as it was suggested in the error log:

```js
import db from './database.js';
```

Or run your script with enabled experimental module es-module-specifier-resolution

```bash
node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer no longer works for node v19 and above, instead try the following, to install a loader that support transpiled code.

```
npm i extensionless
```

Then execute the script as follows,

```
node --loader=extensionless app.js
```

Also ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/extensionless